# Extract URL parameters with regex - repeating a capture group

Tags: php, regex, url, parameters, capturing-group

I'm attempting to extract the URL parameters via regex and am sooo close to getting it to work.  I even know what the problem is: my regex is stumbling on repeated capture groups.  But I simply cannot figure out how to fix it.

Language is PHP.

My URL looks something like the one below.  It can have no parameters, just one or multiple:

```
member.php?action=bla&arg=2&test=15&schedule=16
```

My regex looks like this:

```
member\.php((?:[\?|&](\w*)=(\w*))*)
```

And my capture groups end up being:

```
1. action=bla&arg=2&test=15&schedule=16
2. schedule
3. 16
```

I cannot figure out how to capture all the parameters individually.  Will I just have to settle for the first capture group and explode it myself?  It would be much more elegant for my purposes if I can do all the work inside one regex.

Comment: on what programming language? regex has different flavors in different languages.

Comment: Sorry, this is in PHP (so using PCRE)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
try:
<?php
$str="member.php?action=bla&arg=2&test=15&schedule=16#test";
preg_match_all('/([^?&=#]+)=([^&#]*)/',$str,$m);
print_r($m);

//combine the keys and values onto an assoc array
$data=array_combine( $m[1], $m[2]);
print_r($data);
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) ?

Answer (score 0):

Extract parameters and their values with-> `&[\w]*=[\d]*`