# Determining a regular expression for url for drupal field

Tags: php, regex, drupal

I am looking to try an determine a regular expression to parse out the interior url from this google alert redirect

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://weheartit.com/entry/29409069&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABAo5aK_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=jRWL16jvo8k&usg=AFQjCNGbJMqWtbCxpcJdu4PGD6RToU6NTw
```

What I need to do is remove the first part that is

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=
```

And I would also remove the trailing string which is

```
&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABAo5aK_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=jRWL16jvo8k&usg=AFQjCNGbJMqWtbCxpcJdu4PGD6RToU6NTw
```

So the ending url I would end with is

```
http://weheartit.com/entry/29409069
```

---

I just wanted to update this thanks for the help. This was an issue in the link module for drupal and it has been fixed

Comment: We have some duplicates on this. The regex is super simple. And the alternative with `parse_url` and `parse_str` even more so.

Comment: Well it might super simple to you but i am having alot of trouble anything to work the best I could come up with is                    <?php
function sub_node_save () {

   $url = $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'];
   $url = preg_replace('.*?(http)(.)(.)((?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+)', '', $url);
   $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'] =$url;

return ;

}

?>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract URL from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390556/extract-url-from-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract URL parameters with regex - repeating a capture group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762626/extract-url-parameters-with-regex-repeating-a-capture-group)

Comment: Use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10826259/edit), not comments, for additions to your question.

Comment: not a duplicate exactly because there are 2 urls with the redirect so just detecting the url is not going to help me I need to remove a url and string. Thanks for those other links I appreciate but I am still having trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still unclear what you are trying to accomplish, whether it's extracting or removal of the surrounding parts, it's not really difficult:

```
preg_match('#q=(http://[^&]+)#', $source, $result);
print $result[1];
```

Or otherwise:

```
= preg_replace('#^.+q=([^&]+).+$#', '$1', $source);
```

Would work.

- See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

And again, the alternative lies in [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str)

Comment: I have drupal 7 install that I have a Link module field that is populated by rss feed from google alerts the url that is saved in the field is the google redirect url because thats what google returns from the feed I have another module that formats the url into a url for a screenshot server that does not support redirects properly so I need to get the main url and not url with redirect for the screenshot server to work properly sorry I should have said in the first place thanks for you help Mario does make more sense at all

Comment: What I am doing is making a module that works with the field I have to change and save the new url

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to strip the URL to pieces manually, you can...

```
$ cat parseurl.php 
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$url="http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://weheartit.com/entry/29409069&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABAo5aK_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=jRWL16jvo8k&usg=AFQjCNGbJMqWtbCxpcJdu4PGD6RToU6NTw";

# Parts of this section could be replaced with parse_url()
$junk = explode("?", $url);
$parts = explode("&", $junk[1]);
$gvar = array();
foreach ($parts as $thisone) {
  $junk = explode("=", $thisone);
  $gvar[$junk[0]]=$junk[1];
}

print_r($gvar);

printf("Embedded URL: %s\n", $gvar["q"]);

$ ./parseurl.php 
Array
(
    [sa] => X
    [q] => http://weheartit.com/entry/29409069
    [ct] => ga
    [cad] => CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABAo5aK_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw
    [cd] => jRWL16jvo8k
    [usg] => AFQjCNGbJMqWtbCxpcJdu4PGD6RToU6NTw
)
Embedded URL: http://weheartit.com/entry/29409069
$
```

To do this with parse_url() and parse_str, you might use something like:

```
<?php

$url="http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://weheartit.com/entry/29409069&ct=ga&cad=CAcQARgAIAEoATAAOABAo5aK_gRIAlgBYgVlbi1VUw&cd=jRWL16jvo8k&usg=AFQjCNGbJMqWtbCxpcJdu4PGD6RToU6NTw";

parse_str( parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $gvar );
printf("Embedded URL: %s\n", $gvar['q']);
```

This definitely seems like the easier way to go, but I'll leave the first version so you can see what is (likely) happening "under the hood".  :-)

Comment: Don't forget that parse_str() takes a second argument, an array into which parsed variables will be inserted.  This eliminates your down side.

Comment: DOH!  Right you are, ghoti.  I didn't see that before.  Thanks, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow thanks very much for your help  I am formulating how to use this with drupal right now.

Comment: What I thought might work is not --                                   <?php
function sub_node_save() {

   $url = $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'];
   $url = parse_str( parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $gvar );
   $node->field_web_screenhot['und'][0]['url'] =$url;

return;
}